# Bootstrap dropup div detaching from input source

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to use a bootstrap dropup with a simple auto complete. This issue does not occur with a dropdown, only the dropup.

I have replicated the issue in a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d0haLws6/32/

Accompanying code:

```
const CityListMaster = ["Pheonix", "San Francisco", "Minneapolis", "Tampa Bay", "New York", "Buffalo", "Washington DC", "Seattle"];

let CityListFiltered = [];

function PerformListFilter(filterBy){
    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();
  filterArray = CityListMaster.filter(city => city.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);

  $('#dropdown-autocomplete-menu').html('');
  for(let i = 0; i < filterArray.length; i++){
    $('#dropdown-autocomplete-menu').append('<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">'+ filterArray[i] +'</a>');
  }
}


$('#dropdown-text-input').keyup(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  PerformListFilter(e.target.value);
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    for(let i = 0; i < CityListMaster.length; i++){
    $('#dropdown-autocomplete-menu').append('<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">'+ CityListMaster[i] +'</a>');
  }

})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group dropup">
    <input class="dropdown-toggle" type="text" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdown-text-input">
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-autocomplete-menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (to give space and trigger the dropup):

```
#dropdown-text-input{
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

As you can see, when you start typing, the div detatches from the input source.

I have a feeling it has to do with the bootstrap transform CSS that is baked in to the library. Is there a way that I could manually trigger a 're-draw' or new transformation of the expanded div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a much better answer that somehow I overlooked in the documentation.

```
$('#dropdown-text-input').dropdown('update');
```

This is much smoother and doesn't run into any performance issues that I was seeing with the click method.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can `trigger` a " re-draw " , trigger a `click` event on the `input` right before filtering the list to hide the `dropup`, and another one right after that to re-show the `dropup`

```
function PerformListFilter(filterBy){
  $('#dropdown-text-input').trigger('click'); // to hide it
    filterBy = filterBy.toLowerCase();
  filterArray = CityListMaster.filter(city => city.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);

  $('#dropdown-autocomplete-menu').html('');
  for(let i = 0; i < filterArray.length; i++){
    $('#dropdown-autocomplete-menu').append('<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">'+ filterArray[i] +'</a>');
  }
  $('#dropdown-text-input').trigger('click'); // to re-show it
}
```

a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d0haLws6/75/

Comment: A little 'hackier' than I would have hoped but it seems to work fine with little performance impact so it will do for now thanks!